# What kind of deviation is the $sx$ button on my calculator?

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation

I'm learning about standard deviation and I notice there is another kind of deviation option on my calculator.

The standard deviation is denoted by $\sigma x$ on my calculator while the other kind of deviation is denoted by $sx$.

Just to clarify what $sx$ does, given the data $1,2,3$, $\sigma x=0.816$ while $sx=1.000$.

What is the name of this kind of variance ?

I am assuming it is a kind of variance based on what it does with data.

Comment: It's a question of sample variance vs. population variance.  That is to say, is the denominator $N$ or $N-1$.  Of course, if $N$ is large then the difference is usually negligible.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{2/3} \approx 0.816$. This is called an [unbiased estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation)

Comment: @lulu Oh , so sample variance uses $N$ and is denoted by $\sigma x$, while population variance uses $N-1$ and is denoted by $sx$. Is that correct ?

Comment: Other way round.  On most calculators (or in a system like Excel) the default setting is $N-1$, the sample variance.  In Excel, say, Stdev() gives you the sample s.d., while StdevP() gives you the population s.d.